Remove link to foundry in email notification typescript function
I'm creating an email notification within Foundry using a typescript notification function and it's been requested that I remove the blue box that sends you to Foundry when you click on it. Is there any way to remove this?
Blue Box in Question
import { Function, Edits, OntologyEditFunction, UserFacingError, BasicShortNotification } from "@foundry/functions-api";
import {Notification, EmailNotificationContent, ShortNotification, User } from "@foundry/functions-api";
import{ Objects, ExampleDataSource } from "@foundry/ontology-api";

export class notification_email { 
    @Function()
    public async createfsiNotification(exampleDataSource: ExampleDataSource, user: User): Promise<Notification> {
        const shortNotification = ShortNotification.builder()
            .heading("New ")
            .content("new content")
            .build();

        const emailBody = 'Hello, ${user.firstName}'
        const emailNotificationContent = EmailNotificationContent.builder()
            .subject("new")
            .body(emailBody)
            .build();
        
        return Notification.builder()
        .shortNotification(shortNotification)
        .emailNotificationContent(emailNotificationContent)
        .build();

    }
}

